# Rails form_with (remote) does not see existing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A rails form that posts

```
<%= form_with url: search_results_labours_path do |f| %>
```

gets processed by the controller, but fails to return the expected XHR response with

```
Started POST "/labours/search_results" for ::1 at 2021-02-12 10:12:46 +0100
Processing by LaboursController#search_results as JS
[...]

ActionController::UnknownFormat (LaboursController#search_results is missing a template for
this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/javascript", "*/*"]
request.variant: []):
```

Yet, the template does exist [image: template does exist]

and it calls a partial `_search_results.html.erb`

```
$("div#search_results").html("<%= j render ('labours/results') %>").css({ opacity: 0 }).fadeTo('slow',1);

def search_results  
  @labours = Labour.order(usercontract_id: :asc).where('time_start >= ?', params[:labour][:date_start].to_date.at_beginning_of_day ).all
  index_personnel
end
```

Why does rails not see the template for that action?

**Update**

changing the form to a remote

```
<%= form_with(url: search_results_labours_path, local: true) do |f| %>
```

and processing the partial as a non partial `search_results.html.erb` processes entirely as expected, confirming the problem is in perceiving the existence of `search_results.js.erb` The file also appears, with this spelling via the console to list all files.

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 deploy  staff   105 12 Feb 10:10 search_results.js.erb
```

Comment: Please add the relevant controller action implementation

Comment: update inserted

Comment: It is  a filter checking on the current user and its access rights.